# Autenticações via OAuth para APIs REST

Tags: api, rest, restful, oauth

Em quase todas as APIs de redes sociais é necessário autenticar seu app com OAuth, para poder usar os recursos da mesma.

Como é esse processo?

No meu caso, estou tentando trazer uma lista dos seguidores de um determinado blog pela v2 da API do Tumblr, usando o client em Javascript: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2

Eu tentei procurar alguma solução na documentação do oauth.net mas tudo ficou bem confuso para mim.

Answer (score 1):

Em uma pesquisa no google eu encontrei algumas coisas que pode lhe ajudar a entender como funciona e como é, no blog do Diogo tem uma explicação para detalhar melhor o que é e como funciona a primeira vista é bem complicado mesmo porque foge um pouco ao que estamos acostumados a fazer "simples telas de login e senha".

[Explicação sobre o que e como funciona (Blog Diogo)](http://www.diogomafra.com.br/2010/09/como-funciona-autenticacao-oauth.html)

No caso do tumblr não tem muita diferença do twitter ou facebook, dando uma pesquisada no google eu encontrei alguns exemplos em php e javascript que pode te auxiliar, acho que é mais fácil ver o código e executar para entender mais rápido.

No links tem bastante exemplo, e também esse plugin para wordpress que pode te ajudar também.

1 - [Javascript API Thumblr e Documentação](https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.jsLib)

2 - [PHP API Thumblr e Documentação](https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php)

3 - [Plugin para Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tumblr-widget-for-wordpress/)

Comment: Muito bom este artigo do Diogo @claudsan, os outros 2 links que ele recomenda a leitura no post também são muito bons. Já é um bom começo. Obrigado!