# Protegendo uma rota usada por um único domínio

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tenho uma aplicação em Laravel hospedada em um subdomínio e preciso permitir que sua API (que possui uma única rota POST) seja utilizada unicamente pela aplicação hospedada no domínio principal.

Qual a maneira mais simples de proteger essa rota? Pensei em usar JWT, mas como o uso da rota é automatizado, tinha problemas de token expirado. Também pensei em criar um middleware para checar o user-agent, mas ele pode ser modificado.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: dominio.com

Answer (score 2):

**Proteção de CSRF:**

Se está preocupado de alguém ler o conteúdo, existem duas situações "distintas":

Obter o seu `/json.json` no lado do cliente, via `Javascript/Ajax`.

Obter o seu `/json.json` no lado do "servidor"/"cliente", via `cURL/Wget/Webviewer` (e "navegadores personalizados").

A primeira situação é mais fácil e de fato "há o que fazer" para impedir:

---

Adicionar o cabeçalho de `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, estrito para o seu website.

(Opcional) Adicione o `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, limite os cabeçalhos (ex. `X-CRSF-TOKEN`) que podem ser enviados.

(Opcional) Adicione o `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, limite os métodos aceitos (ex. `GET`) assim somente este método será aceito.

Logo poderá utilizar:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.dominio.com http://m.dominio.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');
```

[Recomendo ver esta resposta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3251/67686)

---

Adicionar um `CSRF Token`.
O CSRF Token deve ser válido apenas para uma única sessão.
(Recomendado) O `CSRF Token` deve ser válido para um único IP.
(Opcional) O `CSRF Token` deve expirá após um único uso.
(Opcional) O `CSRF Token` deve único para cada URL ou para cada seguimento.

[Pode ler esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116437/67686)

---

*Medidas pouco eficientes, mas que podem ajudar:*

Verificar o `Referrer/Origin`, são facilmente falsificados.
A segunda situação é impossível de ser corrigida, literalmente, não há como impedir isso, tudo listado acima não é suficiente para impedir o uso de `cURL/Wget`.

Criar um `Rate-Limit`, um limite de quantas vezes a página pode ser acessada por segundo por IP (ou faixa de `IPv6`) é relativamente eficiente, pois exigirá o uso de vários `proxies` caso deseja obter o conteúdo constantemente, mas lembre-se do `CGNAT` no `IPv4`.
Bloquear acesso via TOR e proxies públicos.

---

*Medidas bem menos eficientes, mas que podem ajudar:*

Criar um "desafio" em Javascript, como por exemplo o `jjencode`, o CloudFlare utiliza isto.

---

**Outras respostas que podem complementar:**

[Api Rest somente lado do servidor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113017/67686)

[Autenticações via OAuth para APIs REST](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13684/67686)

Comment: obrigado pela ótima resposta. O que estou procurando também é evitar que a rota seja usada fora do domínio.